# Which types are supported by XNA's Automatic XNB Serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, xna, content-pipeline

I've read Shawn Harvgreave's blog entry about automatic serialization and the MSDN article on an overview of the content pipeline, but I couldn't find a list of the types supported.

Quoting MSDN:

> Starting with XNA Game Studio 3.1, the serialization of custom data to
>   the .XNB format is done automatically for simple types that do not
>   have an existing content type writer.

I haven't had problems with this until I tried to use a `Queue` from `System.Collections.Generic` which I'm guessing isn't supported by the automatic serialization.

So, is there a list of types supported by this? And if it isn't supported, will I need to write my own `ContentTypeWriter` and `ContentTypeReader`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing a complete list of compatible types is tricky - because the serializer tries to be compatible with custom types it has never seen before. So any list of compatible classes cannot be exhaustive. As [Shawn's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/03/25/automatic-xnb-serialization-in-xna-game-studio-3-1.aspx) says:

> By default it will serialize all the public fields and properties of your type (assuming they are not read-only).

But let's talk about collection classes. By the above rule, collection classes won't be serialized correctly (*when using reflection*), because their collection of objects is not a public property (also, indexers aren't supported).

It's interesting to point out *why* automatically serializing a collection like this isn't a built-in feature. A collection usually implements `IEnumerable<T>` (like `Queue<T>` does), which could be serialized. But that's read-only. There's no standard interface like `IEnumerable` for *writing* to collections. So there's no way to automatically deserialize them!

Fortunately, **XNA provides custom readers/writers for the following generic collection types**:

- Arrays
- `List<T>`
- `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`

The serializer automatically uses custom readers/writers when they are available. So if you want it to handle a collection class (like `Queue<T>`), then you must create your own `ContentTypeWriter` and `ContentTypeReader` for it. Fortunately this isn't too hard - see below for an *untested* implementation.

**For a full list of built-in types, see the [XNB Format](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/sample/xnb_format) specification**. Again this just covers the *built-in* types. Other types can be supported through reflection or by providing custom reader/writer pairs.

---

```
class QueueReader<T> : ContentTypeReader<Queue<T>>
{
    public override bool CanDeserializeIntoExistingObject { get { return true; } }

    protected override Queue<T> Read(ContentReader input, Queue<T> existingInstance)
    {
        int count = input.ReadInt32();
        Queue<T> queue = existingInstance ?? new Queue<T>(count);
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            queue.Enqueue(input.ReadObject<T>());
        return queue;
    }
}

[ContentTypeWriter]
class QueueWriter<T> : ContentTypeWriter<Queue<T>>
{
    public override string GetRuntimeReader(TargetPlatform targetPlatform)
    {
        return typeof(QueueReader<T>).AssemblyQualifiedName;
    }

    public override bool CanDeserializeIntoExistingObject { get { return true; } }

    protected override void Write(ContentWriter output, Queue<T> value)
    {
        output.Write(value.Count);
        foreach(var item in value)
            output.WriteObject<T>(item);
    }
}
```

Note that my implementation of `GetRuntimeReader` here doesn't handle cases where `targetPlatform` isn't Windows. And you'll need to put these in the right assemblies so you don't get dependency issues.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. You confirmed my suspicions.