# Loading level data from xml file in XNA

Tags: c#, xml, oop, xna, xna-4.0

I am creating a tile-based game in XNA and will be loading the level information from xml files. I have no problem with loading xml data but I would like feedback on the approach I'm thinking of using for reading the xml file.

The code has a class hierarchy such that:

A Level class contains:
- a collection of TileLayers
- a collection of Tilesets

A TileLayer class contains
- a collection of Tiles

A Tileset class contains:
- a collection of TilsetTiles

A TilesetTile class contains:
- a TileId
- a collection of TileProperties
- a TileRectangle

Each of the above classes requires some information from the xml level file.

When I load a level I would like to simply call Level.Load();

My intention is that each class will have a Load() method that will:
1. Load any specific info it needs from the xml file.
2. Call Load() on its children.

The problem I see is that the code for processing the xml will be scattered around in different files making changes difficult to implement (for instance if I decide to encrypt the xml file), and no doubt breaks several aspects of the SOLID principles.

I have this idea that I could create an xmlLevelReader class whose sole purpose is to read an xml level file.
This class could then expose methods that can be called from the Load() method in each of the classes described above.

For example the TileLayer class Load() method could call xmlLevelReader.GetTiles() which would return an `IEnumerable<Tile>`

Do you think this approach will work?
Can you foresee any difficulties?
Is this approach too simplistic/complicated?
Any constructive criticism welcomed!

Thanks

Comment: I sincerely suggest looking into using [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/) and importing the data with [TiledLib](https://bitbucket.org/nickgravelyn/tiledlib).

Comment: Why not use the native .NET serialisation mechanisms for this if you want to use your own model?

Comment: @Justin I am using Tiled Map Editor and never knew TiledLib existed, so thank you! Have you used TiledLib yourself? If so perhaps you could post an answer that gives a couple of pointers with regard to using it and 'inflating' classes with the information from the level files? Also, any pointers (or links to references) on the Content Pipeline and how it should/shouldn't be used in conjunction with TiledLib would be a huge help. Thanks

Comment: @millimoose I'm not yet very familiar with serialisation in .Net and I suspect Justin's response means I won't need to use it this time but I will keep it in mind for other uses. Perhaps I could use it for saving game progress. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, I see that you are using Tiled Map Editor. This lead me to suggest that you use TiledLib. Here is a brief explanation of how you can get up and running with importing your .tmx files for use in game.

### Content Pipeline Overview

File -> Content Import -> Content Process -> Content Write -> .xnb -> ContentRead -> Game Object

### TiledLib

TiledLib only handles the `ContentImporter` part of the above diagram. It will essentially handle reading the .tmx XML and allow you to process the data into whatever objects you need at run time. Fortunately, the TiledLib author has provided a Demos section in the download as well.

### Basic Tiled Map Processor Demo

- `BasicDemo` main game project which contains the ContentManager.Load call.
- `BasicDemoContent` project which has the .tmx file from Tiled
- `BasicDemoContentPipeline` project which has the `ContentProcessor`
- `TiledLib` which has the `ContentImporter`

You really only need to worry about how the `ContentProcessor` works because TiledLib handles all the importing for you. Although I do suggest looking through the different classes to understand how it is deserializing the XML (for educational purposes).

The example `ContentProcessor` in the Basic Demo project takes in a `MapContent` object from the `ContentImporter` (TiledLib) and outputs a `DemoMapContent` object which is serialized to .xnb at build time and deserialized to a `Map` object at run time. Here are the classes that represent the map after being processed completely:

```
[ContentSerializerRuntimeType("BasicDemo.Map, BasicDemo")]
public class DemoMapContent
{
    public int TileWidth;
    public int TileHeight;
    public List<DemoMapLayerContent> Layers = new List<DemoMapLayerContent>();
}

[ContentSerializerRuntimeType("BasicDemo.Layer, BasicDemo")]
public class DemoMapLayerContent
{
    public int Width;
    public int Height;
    public DemoMapTileContent[] Tiles;
}

[ContentSerializerRuntimeType("BasicDemo.Tile, BasicDemo")]
public class DemoMapTileContent
{
    public ExternalReference<Texture2DContent> Texture;
    public Rectangle SourceRectangle;
    public SpriteEffects SpriteEffects;
}
```

- A `Map` contains a tile width, tile height, and a list of `MapLayers`.
- A `MapLayer` contains a width, a height, and a list of `Tiles`.
- A `MapTile` contains a texture, a source rectangle (proper rectangle in the tileset), and optional sprite effects (I've never used any).

### How It's Made

I suggest reading the comments of the `ContentProcessor` to understand what is happening, but in brief, this is the basics:

- Load texture data for tile set
- Get source rectangles for each tile from within the texture
- Iterate over all layers of the map
- For each layer, iterate over all tiles
- For each tile, get the proper texture and source rectangle
- Assign all data from the input to the output properly

### Caveats

As long as you stick to basic types (vague, I know), you also do not need to worry about `ContentWriter` and `ContentReader` parts of the content pipeline. It will automatically serialize and deserialize the .xnb files at build and run time, respectively. See a question I asked about this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964904/which-types-are-supported-by-xnas-automatic-xnb-serialization).

Also, you'll notice that if you're using object layers from within Tiled, the demo does not show you how to process those. TiledLib does properly import them, you just need to pull the data out and stick it in your proper classes. I'll try to edit this answer later with an example of how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go into so much detail here. I'll accept this answer because, whilst it doesn't answer my questions about the specific approach I had in mind, it does provide a good alternative method with enough detailed explanation to get me up and running. Even if I choose not to use TiledLib, viewing the code and the Content Pipeline demo will be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting to load in XML without manipulating the data at all, you can just use the built in XNA Content Serializer.

Essentially you define a class which maps to your xml format, and then read the XML into an instance of that class.

For example. Here I define the class I want to load into:

[SpriteRenderDefinition.cs](http://code.google.com/p/mbhxnazombietaxi/source/browse/trunk/ZombieTaxi/MBHEngineContentDefs/Behaviour/SpriteRenderDefinition.cs)

I chose this one because it has nested classes like the case you describe. Note that it goes into the ContentDefinitions project of you XNA solution.

Now here is the xml file that fills in the content of a SpriteRenderDefinition:

[Sprite.xml](http://code.google.com/p/mbhxnazombietaxi/source/browse/trunk/ZombieTaxi/ZombieTaxi/ZombieTaxiContent/GameObjects/Characters/Civilian/Behaviours/Sprite.xml)

The format of that XML maps directly to the member names of SpriteRenderDefinition.

And finally, the code to actually load that XML data into an actual Object at runtime is very straight forward:

```
SpriteRenderDefinition def = GameObjectManager.pInstance.pContentManager.Load<SpriteRenderDefinition>(fileName);
```

After calling that line, you have a SpriteRenderDefintion object populated with all the content of the XML file! That is all the code I wrote. Everything else is built into XNA. It's really quite slick and useful if you take an hour or so to figure it out!

Comment: No problem. I also meant to mention there are a bunch of examples (some much simpler than the SpriteRenderDefinition) here:

http://code.google.com/p/mbhxnazombietaxi/source/browse/trunk/ZombieTaxi/MBHEngineContentDefs/Behaviour/

The associated XML files can be found by drilling down into the sub folders here:

http://code.google.com/p/mbhxnazombietaxi/source/browse/trunk/ZombieTaxi/ZombieTaxi/ZombieTaxiContent/GameObjects/

Let me know if you have any questions!